# Cracking the Interview 19.8- Why did I get a wrong output when I put else in the if-else statement in creating a hashtable

Tags: java, if-statement, hashtable

The question of 19.8 in cracking the interview is: **design a method to find the frequency of occurrences of any given word in a book.**

The solution provided from the book is shown below except I put an `else` in the `createHashtable` function.

I don't know why I get the wrong output(the output is: `1, 0, 0` which should be `2, 1, 1`) when I type the else statement after if.

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Question198
{
  /*create a hashtable for the strings in the book*/
  public static Hashtable<String, Integer> createHashtable(String[] book) {
    Hashtable<String, Integer> table = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < book.length; i++) {
      book[i] = book[i].toLowerCase();
      if(book[i].trim() != " ") {
        if( !table.containsKey(book[i])) {
          table.put(book[i], 0);
        } 
        else{  // ?? why else is here is wrong??
          table.put(book[i], table.get(book[i]) + 1);
        }
      }
    }
    return table;
  }
   /*get the frequency of the given word in the book*/
  public static int getFrequency(Hashtable<String, Integer> table, String word) {
    if( table == null || word == null) return -1;
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    if( table.containsKey(word)) {
      return table.get(word);
    }
    return 0;
  }

/*Test*/
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] book1 = {"This", "is", "a", "is", "case",};
    Hashtable<String, Integer> test1 = createHashtable(book1);
    String word1 = "is";
    String word2 = "a";
    String word3 = "case";
    System.out.println("Expected(2): " + getFrequency(test1, word1));
    System.out.println("Expected(1): " + getFrequency(test1, word2));
    System.out.println("Expected(1): " + getFrequency(test1, word3));
  }

}
```

Comment: Not that it affects the output, but `book[i].trim != " "` will always be `true`. Probably you meant `book[i].trim != ""` (empty `String`)

Comment: And don't use != when comparing strings. Use book[i].trim.equals("")

Comment: @Benoit Thank you for the grammar check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't you need to put 1 initial occurrence ?

```
table.put(book[i], 1);
```

here in the code

```
if( !table.containsKey(book[i])) {
  table.put(book[i], 0);
}
```

and yes `trim()` will not leave `" "` for you in any case

Comment: Thank you. I have rechecked the code in the book, it is starting from 0 in `table.put(book[i], 0)`. @SJuan76, thank you. you are right, the " "in the `book[i].trim != ""`here is "" in the book, but it seems it doesn't affect the output(output is still (1, 0, 0)). when I changed it and test it again. The After I delete the else statement, the output will become (2, 1, 1)

Comment: it is logical thing if you find the item first time you shouldn't make the counter 0, it should be 1, why are you validating against book

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed 0 to 1. It works now. When I first see 0 here, I was also curious about why the author put 0 here, I thought Hashtable might start from index 0 like an array. Now it seems like the book has a print error.Thank you!

Comment: it is not about index it is value that you are putting (mapping)